# Serilog enrichment from context not working

Tags: asp.net-core, logging, serilog

I have a `ASP .NET Core` application and i am trying to enrich the `Serilog` logger  with a property and pass it throghout method calls.
I have used `Serilog.Context` to enrich it to no avail, the property is not present in the log.

**Program**

```
Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration().Enrich.FromLogContext()
                .WriteTo.File(logpath)
                .CreateLogger();
```

**Controller**

```
public class SomeController{

   public ILogger logger=Log.ForContext<SomeController>();
   private SomeService Service;

   public SomeController(SomeService serv)
   {
      this.service=serv;
   }

   [HttpGet]
   public async Task DoSomething()
   {
          string corellationId=Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
          LogContext.PushProperty("id",corellationId);
          service.Run();
    }
}
```

**Service**

```
class SomeService
{
   private ILogger logger=Log.ForContext<SomeService>();
   public void Run()
   {
       logger.Information("I AM NOT SEEING the ID from upstream !");
   }
}
```

Basically i want the  logs of `SomeService` to have the id provided upstream (Controller action).
What i want:

```
"[id] [value]"+ "[SomeService log]"
```

**P.S** The service is injected via dependency injection if it matters.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need to use the `Properties` token in [your `outputTemplate`](https://github.com/serilog/serilog/wiki/Formatting-Output#formatting-plain-text), e.g.

```
var mt = "{LogLevel:u1}|{SourceContext}|{Message:l}|{Properties}{NewLine}{Exception}"
```

when you format the output for your sink e.g.:

```
 .WriteTo.File(logpath, outputTemplate: mt)
```

(ASIDE: You should be [`using` the `LogContext.Push` return value](https://github.com/serilog/serilog/wiki/Enrichment#the-logcontext))

Comment: So in order for me to put a `string` inside the format would a form like this suffice : `"{Timestamp:Yy:Mm:dd HH:mm:ss} [{Level:u3}] {corellationId} {Message}` ?

Comment: yes, if you always do a `using LogContext.Push("corellationId",value)`, then that'll show the value per message (the `{Properties}` token shows all properties not referenced either in the message or the message template)

Comment: I just want to bind the property once per request , when my request enters a `ASP NET Controller` and then  be present in all logs from nested methods.

Comment: You need to use LogContext.Push for that - this can be done in middleware, or by doing a `using (LogContext.Push("req",id))` in your controller etc. Best to got find a good tutorial on Serilog LogContext